# Can't use fragment as parameter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a problem with fragments. I want to create different fragment files, which are connected and displayed in a framelayout inside my mainactivity. Also, it should be possible to switch the fragments with a bottom navigation view.

I created different fragment(blank) classes and they extend the class Fragment, but I'm not able to give these instances of this classes as a parameter to a method called setFragment(Fragment fragment).

Do you know what could cause this problem? My classes extend the class Fragment and so it should be possible to give my own created fragment classes, shouldn't it? +

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it would be helpful to show us some code

Comment: are you trying to achieve fragment replacement from activity bottom navigation view??

Comment: check your imports, e.g. app.fragment vs app.support.v4.fragment or something. They should match in both files

Comment: Problem solved, the import of the right fragment class was the key!
Thank you very much for your chick help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution to your problem is to make your fragments extend `android.app.Fragment` instead of `Fragment`. Everything should work fine after that.**

However, you need to understand the difference between [android.app.fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) and [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment).

If your app uses fragments and you want to support devices before API 11, you have to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. However, if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It helped instant! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different kinds of fragments

```
android.app.Fragment
```

and

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Use `app` fragments with `android.app.FragmentManager`

Use `support` fragments with `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`
It can be obtained by `getSupportFragmentManager()` of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`